# How do I super impose transformed text on a bitmap created from resource and save as JPG?

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

I'm working on an app where the user types something in a textview, then clicks a button. This button starts a thread which super imposes the text on a bitmap in the resources file, then saves this new bitmap to the SD card and starts an intent that allows the user to send/email this image. I have already written this code and it runs on my galaxy vibrant but it doesn't run on the android emulator. This app uses level 8 API and is meant to run on 2.2 platform. I have tried to run this its own thread and also as asynctask with no luck. I have also read many stackoverflow questions and followed their advice on creating bitmaps without overflowing emulator heap size. I've tried instantiating my variables as fields and also within the methods themselves. Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Log.i("INFO","At 2###########");
setContentView(R.layout.blank);
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
}

public void run() {
BitmapFactory.Options factoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
factoryOptions.inPurgeable = true;
factoryOptions.inInputShareable = true;
Bitmap tempCBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.c6,factoryOptions);
cBitmap = tempCBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
PrepareLines();
Bitmap dBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dummy);
Bitmap textLayer = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(dBitmap, w, h, false);
Bitmap workLayer = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(dBitmap, w, h, false);
canvas = new Canvas(textLayer);
canvas.drawText(lineOne, xCenter, yCenter, paint);
canvas.drawText(lineTwo, xCenter, yCenter+20, paint);
canvas.drawText(lineThree, xCenter, yCenter+40, paint);

Camera mCamera = new Camera();
Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
mCamera.save();
mCamera.rotateY(yDegreeRotate+8);
mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
mCamera.restore();

mMatrix.preTranslate(-xCenter, (-yCenter)-verticalOffset);
mMatrix.postTranslate(xCenter, yCenter+verticalOffset);
Log.i("INFO","At before first draw ###########");


canvas.setBitmap(workLayer);
canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(textLayer,0,0,xCenter,h), mMatrix, paint);

canvas.setBitmap(cBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(workLayer, new Matrix(), paint);

mMatrix = new Matrix();
workLayer = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(dBitmap, w, h, false);
dBitmap = null;
System.gc();

mCamera.rotateY(-yDegreeRotate);
mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
// WIN DEATH HERE
mCamera.restore();
// WIN DEATH HERE;
mMatrix.preTranslate(0 , (-yCenter)-verticalOffset);
mMatrix.postTranslate(xCenter, (yCenter)+verticalOffset);
Log.i("INFO","At before second draw ###########");



canvas.setBitmap(workLayer);
canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(textLayer,xCenter,0,w-xCenter,h), mMatrix, paint);

canvas.setBitmap(cBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(workLayer, new Matrix(), paint);

Log.i("INFO","At 20, string measures: "+paint.measureText(message));
canvas = null;
workLayer = null;
textLayer = null;
System.gc();
makeFileAndIntent();
}
```

Here is my most recent logcat output

```
01-14 18:00:43.453: D/AndroidRuntime(388): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
01-14 18:00:43.453: D/AndroidRuntime(388): CheckJNI is ON
01-14 18:00:43.543: D/AndroidRuntime(388): --- registering native functions ---
01-14 18:00:44.063: D/dalvikvm(255): GC_EXPLICIT freed 507 objects / 28896 bytes in 126ms
01-14 18:00:44.173: D/PackageParser(59): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl47264.tmp
01-14 18:00:44.173: W/PackageParser(59): No actions in intent filter at /data/app/vmdl47264.tmp Binary XML file line #30
01-14 18:00:44.443: I/PackageManager(59): Removing non-system package:com.gigabites.fortune
01-14 18:00:44.443: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.gigabites.fortune uid=10040
01-14 18:00:44.543: D/PackageManager(59): Scanning package com.gigabites.fortune
01-14 18:00:44.543: I/PackageManager(59): Package com.gigabites.fortune codePath changed from /data/app/com.gigabites.fortune-2.apk to /data/app/com.gigabites.fortune-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
01-14 18:00:44.543: I/PackageManager(59): /data/app/com.gigabites.fortune-1.apk changed; unpacking
01-14 18:00:44.553: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.gigabites.fortune-1.apk' ---
01-14 18:00:44.803: D/dalvikvm(395): DexOpt: load 37ms, verify 132ms, opt 3ms
01-14 18:00:44.813: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.gigabites.fortune-1.apk' (success) ---
01-14 18:00:44.813: W/PackageManager(59): Code path for pkg : com.gigabites.fortune changing from /data/app/com.gigabites.fortune-2.apk to /data/app/com.gigabites.fortune-1.apk
01-14 18:00:44.823: W/PackageManager(59): Resource path for pkg : com.gigabites.fortune changing from /data/app/com.gigabites.fortune-2.apk to /data/app/com.gigabites.fortune-1.apk
01-14 18:00:44.823: D/PackageManager(59):   Activities: com.gigabites.fortune.FortuneCookieActivity com.gigabites.fortune.NewCookieActivity com.gigabites.fortune.BrowseStockActivity com.gigabites.fortune.BrowseSavedActivity com.gigabites.fortune.SendCookieActivity com.gigabites.fortune.BuildActivity
01-14 18:00:44.833: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.gigabites.fortune uid=10040
01-14 18:00:44.913: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.gigabites.fortune-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.gigabites.fortune-1.apk@classes.dex
01-14 18:00:44.913: D/PackageManager(59): New package installed in /data/app/com.gigabites.fortune-1.apk
01-14 18:00:45.013: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.gigabites.fortune uid=10040
01-14 18:00:45.213: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8993 objects / 895112 bytes in 187ms
01-14 18:00:45.253: D/dalvikvm(116): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1237 objects / 68112 bytes in 69ms
01-14 18:00:45.383: W/RecognitionManagerService(59): no available voice recognition services found
01-14 18:00:45.503: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2329 objects / 127024 bytes in 241ms
01-14 18:00:45.604: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5971 objects / 316560 bytes in 76ms
01-14 18:00:45.613: I/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.gigabites.fortune-2.apk@classes.dex
01-14 18:00:45.613: D/AndroidRuntime(388): Shutting down VM
01-14 18:00:45.623: D/dalvikvm(388): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-14 18:00:46.043: D/AndroidRuntime(401): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
01-14 18:00:46.043: D/AndroidRuntime(401): CheckJNI is ON
01-14 18:00:46.133: D/AndroidRuntime(401): --- registering native functions ---
01-14 18:00:46.543: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.gigabites.fortune uid=10040
01-14 18:00:46.543: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.gigabites.fortune/.BuildActivity }
01-14 18:00:46.563: I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.gigabites.fortune for activity com.gigabites.fortune/.BuildActivity: pid=407 uid=10040 gids={1015}
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59): HistoryRecord{450598a8 com.gigabites.fortune/.BuildActivity} failed creating starting window
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2165)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2220)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1407)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.addStartingWindow(PhoneWindowManager.java:894)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:9007)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:570)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:79)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    ... 13 more
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010059 a=-1}
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:91)
01-14 18:00:46.574: W/WindowManager(59):    ... 17 more
01-14 18:00:46.574: D/AndroidRuntime(401): Shutting down VM
01-14 18:00:46.583: D/dalvikvm(401): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-14 18:00:46.744: W/ActivityThread(407): Application com.gigabites.fortune is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-14 18:00:46.783: I/System.out(407): Sending WAIT chunk
01-14 18:00:46.783: I/dalvikvm(407): Debugger is active
01-14 18:00:46.983: I/System.out(407): Debugger has connected
01-14 18:00:46.983: I/System.out(407): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-14 18:00:47.183: I/System.out(407): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-14 18:00:47.383: I/System.out(407): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-14 18:00:47.583: I/System.out(407): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-14 18:00:47.783: I/System.out(407): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-14 18:00:47.983: I/System.out(407): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-14 18:00:48.183: I/System.out(407): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-14 18:00:48.393: I/System.out(407): debugger has settled (1335)
01-14 18:00:50.373: I/INFO(407): At 2###########
01-14 18:00:50.433: I/INFO(407): At 1###########
01-14 18:00:50.663: D/dalvikvm(407): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 725 objects / 54320 bytes in 39ms
01-14 18:00:51.063: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.gigabites.fortune/.BuildActivity: 4505 ms (total 273315 ms)
01-14 18:00:51.103: I/INFO(407): At 2###########
01-14 18:00:51.103: I/INFO(407): At 20, string measures: 653.0
01-14 18:00:51.164: D/dalvikvm(407): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 425 objects / 18528 bytes in 34ms
01-14 18:00:51.223: D/dalvikvm(407): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 47 objects / 1776 bytes in 31ms
01-14 18:00:51.293: I/INFO(407): At before first draw ###########
01-14 18:00:51.373: D/dalvikvm(407): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 15 objects / 680 bytes in 29ms
01-14 18:00:51.433: D/dalvikvm(407): GC_EXPLICIT freed 12 objects / 456 bytes in 30ms
01-14 18:00:51.576: I/DEBUG(31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-14 18:00:51.576: I/DEBUG(31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'
01-14 18:00:51.583: I/DEBUG(31): pid: 407, tid: 414  >>> com.gigabites.fortune <<<
01-14 18:00:51.583: I/DEBUG(31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad
01-14 18:00:51.583: I/DEBUG(31):  r0 00000000  r1 0000000c  r2 00000027  r3 00000000
01-14 18:00:51.583: I/DEBUG(31):  r4 00000000  r5 deadbaad  r6 00001728  r7 00000000
01-14 18:00:51.583: I/DEBUG(31):  r8 46d2ed10  r9 4185ff74  10 00233e40  fp 4185ff70
01-14 18:00:51.583: I/DEBUG(31):  ip ffffffff  sp 46d2ec80  lr afd154c5  pc afd11dc4  cpsr 40000030
01-14 18:00:51.643: I/DEBUG(31):          #00  pc 00011dc4  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.643: I/DEBUG(31):          #01  pc 0000be1c  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.643: I/DEBUG(31): code around pc:
01-14 18:00:51.643: I/DEBUG(31): afd11da4 1c2bd00b 2d00682d e026d1fb 2b0068db 
01-14 18:00:51.643: I/DEBUG(31): afd11db4 4e17d003 51a02001 4d164798 24002227 
01-14 18:00:51.643: I/DEBUG(31): afd11dc4 f7fb702a 2106ee14 ef10f7fc 05592380 
01-14 18:00:51.643: I/DEBUG(31): afd11dd4 6091aa01 1c116054 94012006 eab6f7fc 
01-14 18:00:51.643: I/DEBUG(31): afd11de4 2200a905 f7fc2002 f7fbeac2 2106ee00 
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31): code around lr:
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31): afd154a4 b0834a0d 589c447b 26009001 686768a5 
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31): afd154b4 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901 
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31): afd154c4 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee 
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31): afd154d4 bdf01c30 0002ae7c 000000d4 1c0fb5f0 
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31): afd154e4 43551c3d a904b087 1c16ac01 604d9004 
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31): stack:
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec40  00000015  
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec44  afd1453b  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec48  afd405a0  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec4c  afd4054c  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec50  00000000  
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec54  afd154c5  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec58  00000000  
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec5c  afd1450d  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec60  afd41724  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec64  afd40328  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec68  00000000  
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec6c  00001728  
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec70  00000000  
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec74  afd147ab  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.653: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec78  df002777  
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec7c  e3a070ad  
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31): #00 46d2ec80  8086caa4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec84  80870eea  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec88  afd418dc  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec8c  afd10510  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec90  afd40328  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec94  fffffbdf  
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec98  afd40328  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ec9c  afd41724  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2eca0  0000a000  [heap]
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2eca4  afd0be21  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31): #01 46d2eca8  afd40328  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecac  afd0be21  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecb0  418cb358  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecb4  80846dad  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecb8  0011cda0  [heap]
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecbc  00118b68  [heap]
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecc0  44f461e0  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecc4  8083d9b9  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecc8  000013fc  
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2eccc  00130eb8  [heap]
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecd0  44f461e0  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecd4  0011cda0  [heap]
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecd8  00240c28  [heap]
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecdc  42c3d5f6  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ece0  4185ff7c  
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ece4  afd0cd81  /system/lib/libc.so
01-14 18:00:51.663: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ece8  0011cda0  [heap]
01-14 18:00:51.673: I/DEBUG(31):     46d2ecec  afc008e3  /system/lib/libstdc++.so
01-14 18:00:52.053: I/BootReceiver(59): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
01-14 18:00:52.073: D/Zygote(33): Process 407 terminated by signal (11)
01-14 18:00:52.143: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2390 objects / 360624 bytes in 80ms
01-14 18:00:52.143: I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{450eb158 com.gigabites.fortune/com.gigabites.fortune.BuildActivity paused=false}
01-14 18:00:52.143: I/ActivityManager(59): Process com.gigabites.fortune (pid 407) has died.
01-14 18:00:52.154: I/UsageStats(59): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.gigabites.fortune
01-14 18:00:52.183: W/InputManagerService(59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 407 uid 10040
01-14 18:00:57.414: D/dalvikvm(255): GC_EXPLICIT freed 224 objects / 15056 bytes in 118ms
01-14 18:01:05.203: D/dalvikvm(262): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2061 objects / 147680 bytes in 127ms
01-14 18:01:06.103: D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Edits: Added logcat and tried to run using a basic XML layout on setContentView() to make sure it has nothing to do with my layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your emulator set up correctly? Try looking at your avd editor in eclipse and make sure you have a sd card set up.

Comment: Yeah, I have a 16 megabyte SD card in set up in the emulator. In my code, where it says //WIN DEATH HERE comment is around where my app crashes when I do step over debugging.

Comment: When you get a chance go ahead and edit your question and post a logcat dump of your errors so I can see what its doing when it crashes.

Comment: There, I posted it, just tried to run it again right now and that's the logcat I pasted. I've looked up the meaning of GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC and GC_EXPLICIT...I think it has something to do with that but find it weird that the memory is being used up so fast when I have only 3 decoded bitmaps at 640 by 480 each. And in the past, I've created a live wallpaper out of an array of over 16 bitmaps that just keep being drawn to create animation without a problem.

Comment: Its possible that because you dont use mCamera.save() before your calling mCamera.restore(). I noticed up above the first time you call mCamera.save() and then call mCamera.restore(). my guess is that it causes a crash cause it has nothing to restore. That could also be why in the logcat it says its failing to build the window cause theres nothing saved. try surrounding mCamera.restore() in a try/catch and in the catch try mCamera.save() first and then mCamera.restore(). That could work but I dont know with out seeing the whole project.